# API Routing issues Laravel using Heroku Deployment

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, deployment

I am new to Laravel and I am building a simple contact validation API. I am mainly using API routes over the web routes. As in, I am trying to access exampledomain.com/api/service.
None of the API routes are working, only the index web view. The API routes are returning the error: `404 not found nginx`. The API is deployed on Heroku. Any ideas on what this could be?

Comment: sounds like you have not configured the "pretty urls", url rewriting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an easy out. Heroku includes great docs and all I had to do was find the right documentation for a Laravel specific application. [Laravel Heroku Deploy Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel)